# Electron: project fails at start script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, atom-editor

Well, I've scoured the internet for an answer, but I haven't found a definitive one that works.

It's gotten to the point of downloading the example from [Electron's website](https://electronjs.org) and taking the scripts and putting them straight into my project. Here is the error that I get when launching it from my project (although it works fine with Electron's example repository):

```
electron . 
sh: electron: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! Obfus@1.0.0 start: electron .
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Obfus@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've updated `npm` and `Electron` to ensure that they're up to date, but it still fails constantly. Any suggestions? Thanks so much! (Also, if you'd like to see what the console says, please tell me - I found it a bit too long to be put in a question like this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Electron globally like so

`npm install -g electron`

Do you get the same error message if you install and run right after each other in the same terminal?

```
npm install -g electron
electron .
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked after reinstalling node.js and running that. You are a life saver!

Comment: Glad I can help. Make sure it works if you open a new terminal as well. Depending on how you installed `node` (and therefore `npm`), the path to global dependencies doesn't stick.